# bad inodes reappear after fsck() for vps guests

Tags: mount, fsck, inode, snapshot, vps

I have several vps guests that were created by virt-resize. I do daily backups on the guests by creating a snapshot and rsync file contents. But some of them don't have a clean disk image.

As soon as I do a snapshot and mount the snapshot logical volume:

```
lvcreate -L5G -s -n guest15_snapshot /dev/vgroup/guest15
mount -o loop,offset=262144 /dev/group/guest15_snapshot /mnt/snapshot_dir
```

Bad inocdes are found through `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jul  2 11:21:41 server lvm[10346]: Monitoring snapshot group-guest17_snapshot
Jul  2 11:21:41 server kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_orphan_get: bad orphan inode 198!  e2fsck was run?
Jul  2 11:21:41 server kernel: ext4_test_bit(bit=197, block=145) = 0
Jul  2 11:21:41 server kernel: inode=(null)
Jul  2 11:21:41 server kernel: EXT4-fs (loop0): recovery complete
Jul  2 11:21:41 server kernel: EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Jul  2 11:21:42 server lvm[10346]: No longer monitoring snapshot group-guest17_snapshot
Jul  2 11:21:46 server lvm[10346]: Monitoring snapshot group-guest19_snapshot
Jul  2 11:21:46 server kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_orphan_get: bad orphan inode 25964!  e2fsck was run?
Jul  2 11:21:46 server kernel: ext4_test_bit(bit=1387, block=148) = 0
Jul  2 11:21:46 server kernel: inode=(null)
Jul  2 11:21:46 server kernel: EXT4-fs (loop0): recovery complete
Jul  2 11:21:46 server kernel: EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Jul  2 11:22:22 server lvm[10346]: No longer monitoring snapshot guest-vm19_snapshot
```

I tried `guestfish`:

```
guestfish -a /dev/vgroup/guest17
><fs> run
><fs> fsck ext4 /dev/sda1
```

Most of the time it returned `0x1`, which meant that the error is fixed.

But once I mount the images again, the bad inodes reappear.

How to permanently fix the bad inodes?